# How should I go about web scraping all of the locations on this website: 'https://shoppers.instacart.com/instacart-jobs'

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

My goal is to scrape the every location where Insta-Cart operates into an excel spreadsheet instead of manually inputting each city and state.

This is my R code:

```
#install.packages('robotstxt')
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
library(robotstxt)

#RobotTxts to see if able to scrub data
paths_allowed(paths = c('https://shoppers.instacart.com/instacart-jobs'))

# Reading html texts from website
insta_cart <- read_html('https://shoppers.instacart.com/instacart-jobs') 
print(insta_cart)
```

Output:
TRUE
{html_document}

[1] \n\n\n\n\n  gon.citiesInCurrentStat ...

The website 'https://shoppers.instacart.com/instacart-jobs' shows that the city and state data is in
: < div class="state-collection">

```
insta_cart %>%
  html_node(".state-collection") %>%
  html_text()
```

Output: NA

Do you know what I am doing wrong or have any insight to troubleshooting?

Comment: try to extract ,"stateJobsPageUrl for example ,"stateJobsPageUrl":"https://shoppers.instacart.com/state-jobs/jobs-in-new_jersey" then extract "cityJobsPageUrl" from statejobpageurl link ("cityJobsPageUrl":"https://shoppers.instacart.com/instacart-jobs-in-yardville-bordentown-nj"). basically you need to do scraping at 2 levels

Comment: So I am trying to extract the data using html_node(stateJobsPageUrl) and it is pulling up NA. Do you know how I go about extracting the from the stateJobsPageUrl